# Emacs 25.1 on lubuntu 16.04 won't configure due to missing libpng

Tags: emacs, emacs25

I am attempting to install emacs 25.1 on lubuntu 16.04, and having some trouble. After downloading and extracting the tar, I navigate to the emacs 25.1 directory then..
    `./configure`

The configuration stops when I receive the message

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
    libpng
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
If you don't want to link with them give
     --with-png=no
as options to configure
```

When I try `sudo apt install libpng-dev`

I get the message

`Note, selecting 'libpng12-dev' instead of 'libpng-dev'
libpng12-dev is already the newest version (1.2.54-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.`

I tried reinstalling libpng12-dev using the below string, which didn't help at all.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpng12-0=1.2.54-1ubuntu1
```

I'm stuck here, I've googled around for a while and can't find any solutions that have actually worked.

Comment: Looks like you have the correct (current) `libpng-dev` package. You may need to debug via the `configure` logs why Emacs thinks you have no png library.  As an alternative, consider a prebuilt Emacs 25.1 for Ubuntu from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-elisp/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: I used the prebuilt Emacs from the PPA you linked. Thank you so much, very helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem. After I checked the `config.log` file, I found out that because I already installed *Anaconda3 python*

when gcc compile emacs it uses some `libpng...` found in *Anconda3 directory*.
So I remove related *Anaconda3 directory* in `PATH`, everything turns out right.

The wrong version:

```
configure:15301: result: -lz
configure:15407: checking for png
configure:15437: gcc -o conftest  -g3 -O2 -I/etc/anaconda3/include/libpng16       conftest.c -lpng16 -lz -lm -lX11   >&5 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng16
```

The right version:

```
configure:15301: result: -lz
configure:15407: checking for png
configure:15437: gcc -o conftest  -g3 -O2 -I/usr/include/libpng12       conftest.c -lpng12 -lz -lm -lX11   >&5 
configure:15437: $? = 0
configure:15452: result: yes
```

Hope that would be helpful!

Comment: Removing (or commenting out) the line `export PATH=/vol/home/user/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` from my .bashrc did the trick. I had to start a new terminal though, only calling `$ . .bashrc` did not work. Make sure to check if the changes are in effect, for example by checking if `which python` points to the conda folder (bad) or to the system default (good). After the installation just add the line back in.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to remove the default version of libpng-dev (1.2) and explicitly install version 1.6: `sudo apt-get remove libpng-dev && sudo apt-get install libpng16-dev`

Explicit versions of dependencies don't seem to be documented in the readme files.

Comment: But removing libpng12-dev removes gtk-3 and i am unable to install gtk-3 which says dependency problems and says depends on libpng-dev